# Prestashop Friendly URL's with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, friendly-url

I'm trying to enable friendly URL in prestashop. Clean fully installation of prestashop and apache server. Apache's mod_rewrite is enabled; I've tried cleaning caché, forcing compilation and several attemts to more solutions googled.

Any suggestions? When Friendly URL's off, everything works fine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is wrong when  friendly URL's are enabled ? Do you get some error ? Did you enable debug mode in that case ? Also check root to see if .htaccess file is generated.

Comment: Friendly URL's enabled, 404 error when going to contact page. Where to enable debug mode? .htaccess generated correctly ;) Thanks @PH_Laza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved. I had an issue between ssl and friendly URL's. I've solved by configuring defauls-ssl.conf into `apache2/sites-enabled`

**Here is the config for your yoursite-ssl.config:**

```
ServerAdmin admin@yourserver.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/your/folder/page/
ServerName yourweburl.com

Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
<Directory /path/to/your/folder/page/ >
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#   SSL Config
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/yourwebsslcertificate.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/yourwebsslcertificate.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/yourwebsslcertificate.cert

</VirtualHost>
```